# What would be the best VB.net Recording Control or Add-on?

Tags: audio, vb.net

I tried all the easy ways to add Sound recording from a Microphone.
All of them result in having lots of background noises.
I wonder if there is something for VB.net that has a graphical interface and background noise filters. Need to come with an example.
I am willing to invest into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Capture Control](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl.html) that’s part of the LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor).

The control allows you to select which audio capture device to use through the [AudioDevices Property](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl-audiodevices.html) then you can control which input of the device to use through the [AudioInputs Property](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl-audioinputs.html). Finally, you can try different values for the audio input properties such as Bass, Pan and Treble to see if they have useful effect on the recorded quality, which is done through the selected [audio input class members.](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/audioinput--members.html)

If you would you like to try this .NET control, you can download the [free SDK evaluation from this page](https://leadtools.com/downloads), which includes free technical support through chat and email during the evaluation period.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the best answer as is not vb.net.  But with a third party like Adobe Audition, you can record in that, save the file as mp3, for example, and code that file to be saved into your vb.net code to play at the proper time.